# Why `Deferred<T>.resolve` accept `IWhenable<T>` instead of `any`?

Tags: typescript

I'm using Q library with TypeScript and the type definition of [Q.Deferred.resolve](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/q/index.d.ts#L39) accept `IWhenable<T>` when it looks like it should get `any` because you can pass any value to `resolve`.

Also when I force conversion the code works.

So the question is why is that value definition built like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it looks like it should get  any`because you can pass any value to`resolve`.

No, you can only resolve a `Deferred<any>` with any value. You will need to pass a `T` (or a `PromiseLike<T>`, together: a `IWhenable<T>`) to the `resolve` method of a `Deferred<T>`.

Comment: In this test https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/q/q-tests.ts#L257 they use `Q.resolve("")` and on another `Q.resolve(2)`

Comment: @IdoRan And one returns a `Q.Promise<string>` while the other returns a `Q.Promise<number>`. As expected.

Comment: @IdoRan Also notice that the `Q.resolve` function is not the same as the `.resolve` method of a `Deferred` instance.

Comment: sorry, now I see `IWhenable<T> = PromiseLike<T> | T` I've missed that or T